# h2ogpt: unable to add document to collection to chat

Tags: document, h2ogpt

In h2ogpt I am unable to add document to collection to chat.

https://docs.h2o.ai/h2ogpte-docs/guide/collections/add-documents-to-a-collection states to click on "Add documents" however I do not see this button in the UI.

I copied my document to the Directory of my collection and clicked on "Update DB with new/changed files on disk" as well as "Synchronize DB and UI" but it still shows 0 documents in my collection.

Any ideas?

I have already opened https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/issues/1399 but cross posting here in case of any faster turnaround time for anything that I might be missing, any known workaround or fix etc.

Comment: what worked for me is to manually run python src/make_db.py --add_if_exists=True --user_path=... with my data in user_path. Though it got added to UserData collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me is to manually run python src/make_db.py --add_if_exists=True --user_path=... with my data in user_path. Though it got added to UserData collection...